# Repeatedly check if child object has changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm just getting started with state machines. One of my requirements is that it sends of a request, and awaits a reply. The request creates a child attribute, and the recipient can decline or accept.

What I want to listen for is changed in the childs `approved` attribute, which is a boolean. If it's true, then proceed to X, else proceed to Y.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to write a method that I can use in the state machine that essentially checks if the child attribute has changed (say it waits and checks for 10 seconds). I don't mind having the user wait.

Currently my state machine using AASM looks like this:

```
  aasm column: 'state' do
    state :pending, initial: true
    state :connecting
    state :unavailable
    state :requesting
    state :declined
    state :processing
    state :finished
    state :errored

    event :connect, after: :find_recipient do
      transitions from: :pending, to: :connecting
    end

    event :unavailable do
      transitions from: :connecting, to: :unavailable
    end

    event :request do
      transitions from: :connecting, to: :requesting
    end

    event :decline do
      transitions from: :requesting, to: :declined
    end

    # if recipient is found
    event :process, after: :charge_card do
      transitions from: :connecting, to: :processing
    end

    # payment succeeded
    event :finish, after: :track_payment do
      transitions from: :processing, to: :finished
    end

    # payment failed
    event :fail do
      transitions from: :processing, to: :errored
    end
  end
```

So currently I have a background job that starts when an `Order` is created (which is this model. It initiates the state machine with `order.connect!`

now currently it moves to `requesting` so that's where I'd like to create a method that essentially goes something like:

```
def await_reply
  # access self.request and see the value of request.approved 
  # if approved haven't changed then proceed to self.unavailable!
  # if approved is true then proceed to self.process!
  # if approved is false then proceed to self.decline!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to wait?
You can just use `order.approved?` to check if it is approved.